# Best way for set date creation of file, which downloaded by filestream

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I have part of code which download file from ftp server using FileStream class:

```
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath +
                                        "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" +
                                        ftpServerIP + "/" + fileName));
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

And when i downloaded this file i have FileStream object, which has SafeFileHandle property and probably by this property i may to change date creation of this file, if any have examples for this operation or some links please write in answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use;

```
File.SetCreationTime(fileName, fileDateTime);
```

You will have to do that once you have saved file to directory

Comment: Yes, i think this is simpliest way, but every time bind again by filename maybe is not best practice, when we already have file handle..

Comment: I don't think you have an alternative, filestream doesn't contain any file metadata, but couldn't say for sure.